# Image url in JSON (RABL, Dragonfly, Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rabl, dragonfly-gem

I'm using RABL gem, my user model has many posts

**users/show.rabl**

```
object @user
    attributes :id, :name

    child :posts do
        extends "posts/post"
    end
```

**posts/_post.rabl**

```
attributes :id, image: post.image.url
```

I want to show post's image, but i have an error: *undefined local variable or method "post"*.

But in posts/_post.html.erb i can use this <%= post.image.url =%>

Images loaded by dragonfly gem.

How can i get this image url in json format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a child-attribute you can append it back to the root node by using glue.

Like this:

```
@post
attributes :id, :image_url

glue @image do
  attributes :url => :image_url
end
```

Or perhaps like this:

```
@post
attributes :id

node :image_url do |post|
  post.image.url
end
```